# CSS styling: selector for facebook markup

Tags: html, css, facebook, fbml

Is there a way to target or select the following element in CSS, or similar FBML element?

```
<fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could add a class to it like below.

```
<fb:login-button class="strange"></fb:login-button>
```

Then in the CSS

```
.strange{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:#cc0000;
display:block;
}
```

**OR**

you could add an id to it.

```
<fb:login-button id="strange"></fb:login-button>
```

Then in the CSS file.

```
#strange{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#cc0000;
    display:block;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `fb:` on the beginning of the FBML tag name is an [XML namespace prefix](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-using). By my understanding the FBML is being embedded in an HTML document so it's not the default namespace. CSS2 and earlier don't provide a mechanism for selecting elements that aren't in the default namespace.

As of CSS3 you can qualify type (tag name) selectors with a namespace by separating them with a vertical bar, for example `fb|login-button`. I'm not sure if CSS automatically inherits the namespace prefixes declared on the document. If not, you'll need to use an `@namespace` declaration to register the namespace prefix. For more info, see [the CSS3 Namespaces module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-namespace/#css-qnames).

Answer (score 2):

Syntactically, it is a namespaced element. In practice you can just use:

```
fb\:login-button {
    border: 10px solid red;
}
```